# Column Count in Firefox not working properly

Tags: php, css, multiple-columns

I am having an issue with Firefox not displaying the column-counts properly. It works perfectly in Chrome and IE but for some strange reason it doesn't work in Firefox as it should.
The code is this

```
`<div  style=" margin-left:25px; 
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
column-count: 2; 
height:100%; 
padding-bottom:20px;">`
```

any help would be appreciated.
You can see the page in question
[Here](http://thestuff.exchange)

Comment: its looking fine on firefox 36

Comment: Are you sure? I am only seeing the list of categories as one column, it should be two.

Comment: looks like there is some conflict between column-count and table, i tried various solutions, the best one i can say is to use grids, it will be very compatible with older browsers too, IE10 started supporting column and grid frameworks are very handy for such tasks. Secondly you can use `display:flex`.